# How to correct htaccess redirect loop error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

The following code in my htaccess file is creating a "This webpage has a redirect loop ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" error in all browsers I've tested.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

The code is based on @anubhava's contribution https://stackoverflow.com/a/26914740/1459653

The code seemed to work fine in tests I conducted using http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

However, once implemented, the error occurred and according to the Redirect Mapping tool at https://varvy.com/tools/redirects/ there are 19 Redirect(s) with a "Final status code: 301" for each of www  ||  www (https)  ||  no www (https)

```
http://www.example.com
301 redirect
https://example.com/
https://example.com/
301 redirect
https://example.com/
https://example.com/
301 redirect
```

My intention is to redirect so all permutations (example.com / www.example.com / https://www.example.com / http://example.com)  result in being redirected to https://example.com/ (which is how the SSL certificate is issued).

Comment: The SSL certificate seems to be in good shape. It scored an "A' in the evaluation by https://casecurity.ssllabs.com/

Comment: Actually.. your code is not correct

Comment: Can you be more specific please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not correct. What you meant to do is this,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Specifically you were saying if not `www.example.com` redirect to `example.com`, so it redirects to `example.com` and then it's not `www.example.com` so it does it again and so on. Hence the redirect loop.

Comment: Boom! And just like that @Panama Jack fixed the problem AND taught me where I went wrong!